# I need to output all numbers between 0 and 10 and print "buzz" on odd numbers

Tags: bash, shell

Provide a simple script (language of your choice) that outputs all numbers between 0 and 10 and prints "buzz" on odd numbers.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please have look here: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: The point of a fizzbuzz exercise is to determine if you have the base competence to answer it _on your own_. If you're asking people for help, that defeats the point.

Comment: More to the point, to be on-topic here a question needs to be about a narrow, specific technical problem you encountered _while writing a program yourself_. "Please write this code for me" questions are categorically off-topic.

Comment: ...for some history around why questions of this general flavor get asked, see https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is not a homework or interview problem solving service. But here is something that meets all the criteria of the specification.

> Provide a simple script (language of your choice) that outputs all numbers between 0 and 10 and prints "buzz" on odd numbers.

- ☑ This is a script.
- ☑ Chosen language is POSIX-shell.
- ☑ Outputs all numbers between 0 and 10 and prints "buzz" on odd numbers.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF
0
1 buzz
2
3 buzz
4
5 buzz
6
7 buzz
8
9 buzz
10
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a loop:

**Using Bash:**

```
$ for x in {0..10}; do [[ $((x % 2)) -eq 1 ]] && echo "$x buzz" || echo "$x"; done
0
1 buzz
2
3 buzz
4
5 buzz
6
7 buzz
8
9 buzz
10
```

**Using Python**:

```
$ python3 -c "for x in range(11): print(x, 'buzz') if x % 2 else print(x)"
0
1 buzz
2
3 buzz
4
5 buzz
6
7 buzz
8
9 buzz
10
```

Comment: Fails to satisfy the following specification statement: `outputs all numbers
between 0 and 10`.

Comment: It looks like I would have failed the question :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Using awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=10;i++){print(i%2==0?i:i" buzz")}}'
awk '{$1%2==0?$0:$0=$0" buzz"}1' <(seq 0 10)
awk '{$1%2==0?$0:$0=$0" buzz"}1' <(echo {0..10}|tr ' ' '\n')
awk -v s="0" -v e="10" -v b="buzz" 'BEGIN{while(s<=e){print(s%2==0?s:s" "b);s++}}'
```

**Using bash**

```
for i in {0..10}; do [[ "$i"%2 -eq 0 ]] && echo "$i" || echo "$i buzz"; done
for ((i=0;i<=10;i++)); do [[ "$i"%2 -eq 0 ]] && echo $i || echo "$i buzz"; done
i=0; while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do [[ "$i"%2 -eq 0 ]] && echo "$i" || echo "$i buzz"; ((i++)); done
i=0; until [ "$i" -gt 10 ]; do [[ "$i"%2 -eq 0 ]] && echo "$i" || echo "$i buzz"; ((i++)); done
xargs -i bash -c '[[ "{}"%2 -eq 0 ]] && echo "{}" || echo "{} buzz"' < <(seq 0 10)
```

Comment: Fails to satisfy the following specification statement: `outputs all numbers
between 0 and 10`.

Comment: @LéaGris. you mean i have to output the odd numbers too?

Comment: That's what the specification statement reads. But most/all the answers just did not get it.

Comment: @LéaGris.. ok . updated